# Azure DevOps Pipeline failing at NuGet restore task

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a Azure function Project in Visual studio 2019. Everything works great on my desktop but the project is failing at NuGet Restore task in Azure DevOps Pipeline with below error.

**Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1**

2020-06-09T08:32:02.2578449Z ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in E:\agent_work\491\s\CPUSRETools\AzureCapacityUsage\AzureCapacityUsage.csproj
    Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.)

2020-06-09T08:32:02.2592475Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in E:\agent_work\491\s\CPUSRETools\AzureCapacityUsage\AzureCapacityUsage.csproj%0D%0A    Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)%0D%0A    Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)%0D%0A    Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http 3.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http 3.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)%0D%0A    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.)

2020-06-09T08:32:02.2594955Z ##[debug]task result: Failed

2020-06-09T08:32:02.2595537Z ##[error]Packages failed to restore

Comment: 1) https://zimmergren.net/azure-devops-vsts-package-version-is-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp-supports-netstandard/

2) https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2040

both the links can help you.

Comment: I still have this problem. as suggested in you link, I tried using .NET Restore instead of NuGet Restore. Still similar errors

 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.806\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a work around for my issue.
I have 9 Projects that I getting built fine using VSBuild Task. One project is failing to build in VSBuild Task. So I moved that task to a new Solution.
Pointed the VSBuild to old Solution which has 9 projects and Pointed the .NET Build Task to new Solution file which was failing in VSBuild.

Now world is colorful again.

Answer (score 1):

It showed from the error that the dotnet task was using version 2.1.806 dotnet sdk. But your project is targeting dotnet 3.1.

You can use task [Use .Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) to use the specific version .Net Core (version 3.1) in your pipeline. See below

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: sdk
    version: 3.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: '**\*.csproj'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Levi Lu. Adding "Use .NET Core sdk 3.x " and dotnet restore did the trick.
However, my final step of building the solution file is failing. It is not able to get any references 
Error: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you used vsbuild task to build your project. You can try setting  `restoreNugetPackages` to `true`. Or you can try using dotnet build task.

Comment: I tried VSBuild Task with Restore NuGet Package Option. It failed with error "The 'Restore NuGet Packages' option is deprecated. To restore NuGet packages in your build, add a NuGet Tool Installer task to your build definition."

Also, I tried dotnet build it is failing with multiple errors like "The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"